# Css\javascript transitions

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I'm trying to optimize website, which has alot of different scripts, aswell as alot of graphics transition. SOme of them are css3, some js(with some framework) So which part of computer responsible for rendering transition? Is it cpu or gpu?

Comment: CPU is always involved but there is no standardization regarding GPU usage across browsers and OS. Do you have a specific practical question/problem ?

Comment: I know that cpu always working, but i wasn't sure if gpu does any work aswell. This website using 100% of cpu while opened in any browser. And i'm trying to figure which part of it responsible for using so much resources

Comment: [Profile your application](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles) to locate the problem.